# How can I populate Google line chart with data from mySQL database. (single file / Inline solution)

Tags: mysql, charts, google-visualization, flatpickr

I have an MCU (ESP8266) with a temperature and humidity sensor.
The MCU sends the measurement data via MQTT to an MQTT broker running on my Synology NAS.
Also running on the NAS is an MQTT client (Node.js) that writes the received data to the MySQL database on the NAS.
Last but not least, a web server and PHP server are also running on the NAS.

Now I want to make a website to display the data from the db as a line chart.

> **Questions:**
>
> - How can I populate Google line chart with data from mySQL database?
> - It's possible to use one single file (.php) to do this?
> - How can I manage a date range selection?
> - How can i select / deselect lines on the chart?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like many problems cramped into one question

Comment: You guys are really fast.. During the complicated writing of the answer already - 1 Karma :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here my answer to my question.

Since I have no big idea of the used programming languages, I had to search, read and test a lot of sources in the web to copy the result together :-)
I will extend it a bit in future, but for me it works perfectly.

I would like to present this solution here to help others get started.
However, there are certainly many ways to improve the code. 
If someone wants to, I'd be happy about suggestions.
Complete File on Github.
https://github.com/DIYDave/MySQL-and-Google-Line-Chart

1. PHP. Read the data from the db and returns a JSON string to javascript

```php
<?php
function getData(){
 // Connect to MySQL (db Hostname/IP, user, password, database)
    $link = new mysqli( '192.168.10.10', 'user', 'password', 'mymqttdb' );
    if ( $link->connect_errno ) {
        die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $link->connect_errno . ") " . $link->connect_error );
    }   
    $start = $_GET['startDate'];        // Get parameter from URL
    $ende = $_GET['endDate'];           // Get parameter from URL

    if (!isset($endDate )){             // No end date? then actual for end
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', time());
    }   
    if (!isset($startDate )){           // No start date? then actual -1 day for start
        $startDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($ende)));
    }
    // Query in SQL ! add your own columns and database table name!
    $query= "SELECT `DateTime`,`temperature`,`humidity` FROM `Chickenhouse` WHERE `DateTime` BETWEEN" . "'" . $startDate ."'" . "AND" . "'" . $endDate ."'";
    $result = $link->query($query);     // make db query

    $rows = array();
    $table = array(); 

    $table['cols'] = array
    (
        array('label' => 'Date Time', 'type' => 'datetime'),
        array('label' => 'Temperatur (°C)', 'type' => 'number'),        // Select your label for the index
        array('label' => 'Luftfeuchtigkeit (%)', 'type' => 'number')    // Select your label for the index
    ); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))       // got to all the lines of the query result
    {
        $sub_array = array();
        $date1 = new DateTime($row['DateTime']);
        $date2 = "Date(".date_format($date1, 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($date1, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($date1, 'd').", ".date_format($date1, 'H').", ".date_format($date1, 'i').", ".date_format($date1, 's').")";
        $sub_array[] =  array("v" => (string)$date2);
        $sub_array[] =  array("v" => $row["temperature"]);
        $sub_array[] =  array("v" => $row["humidity"]);
        $rows[] =  array("c" => $sub_array);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $lineCount = count($rows);                          // Number of array fields (lines) to show in browser
    return array(json_encode($table), $lineCount);      // Make JSON from array and give it to the java script together with linecount
}
?>
```

2. CSS and HTML. More or less just for formatting and setting placeholders.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.css">
<style>
*{font-family:Arial;}
    .page-wrapper{ width:90%; margin:0 auto; }
    input { border: 2px solid whitesmoke;border-radius: 12px; padding: 12px 10px; text-align: center;  font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; width: 250px;background: cornflowerblue; color: yellow;}
    button { border: none; border-radius: 10px; text-align: center; padding: 12px 10px; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; background: cornflowerblue; color: white;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">  </div>  
    <input type="text" style="float:left" id="rangeDate" placeholder="Select Timespan" data-input>
    <br>
    <p id="LineCount" > </p>
    <div id="line_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 800px"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
```

3. Javascript. Google chart. Accepts the JSON data and displays it as a line diagram. Here are many options possible. 
   Details here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

```
// Setup and show Google line chart
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart(){
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo getData()[0]?>);       //  Call PHP-Function an receive JSON
    document.getElementById("LineCount").innerHTML= "  " + <?php echo getData()[1]?> + " Records loaded";   // Get record count
    var options = {
        series: {
            0:{color: 'red', visibleInLegend: true, targetAxisIndex: 0},
            1:{color: 'blue', visibleInLegend: true, targetAxisIndex: 1}
        },
        vAxes: {
            // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
            0: {title: 'Temp (°C)' }, // , 'minValue': 0, 'maxValue': 30
            1: {title: 'Feuchte(%)'}
        },
        title:'Chickenhouse',
        legend:{position:'top'},
        chartArea:{width:'75%', height:'65%'},
        //curveType: 'function',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Datum',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},
            format: 'd.M HH:mm',
            slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:80
        },
        explorer: { 
            actions: ['dragToPan', 'dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],  // 'dragToZoom' 
            axis: 'horizontal',
            keepInBounds: true,
            maxZoomIn: 28.0,
            maxZoomOut: 1.0,
            zoomDelta: 1.5
        },
        colors: ['#D44E41'],
    };
    var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ // Tooltip format
    pattern: "dd.MM.yyyy -   HH:mm"
    }); 
    date_formatter.format(data, 0);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

4. Javascript. Selection of displayed lines by clicking on the legend.

   ```
   // Select / deselect lines by clicking on the label
       var columns = [];
   var series = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
       columns.push(i);
       if (i > 0) {
           series[i - 1] = {};
       }
   }
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
       var sel = chart.getSelection();
       // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
       if (sel.length > 0) {
           // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
           if (sel[0].row === null) {
               var col = sel[0].column;
               if (columns[col] == col) {
                   // hide the data series
                   columns[col] = {
                       label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                       type: data.getColumnType(col),
                       calc: function () {
                           return null;
                       }
                   };

                   // grey out the legend entry
                   series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
               } else {
                   // show the data series
                   columns[col] = col;
                   series[col - 1].color = null;
               }
               var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
               view.setColumns(columns);
               chart.draw(view, options);
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   };
5. Javascript. Flatpickr. Cool javascript app to select date and time. It's also possible to select date ranges what I use here.  https://flatpickr.js.org/

```
// Flatpickr to select date range
$("#rangeDate").flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    mode: 'range',
    time_24hr: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    maxDate: "today",
    defaulDate: "today",
    onClose: function test(selectedDates, dateStr, instance){
        arDateTime = dateStr.split(" to ");
        dateTimeStart = arDateTime[0] + " 00:00" ;
        dateTimeEnd =  arDateTime[1] + " 23:59" ;
        strNeu = "?startDate=" + dateTimeStart + "&endDate=" + dateTimeEnd;
        window.location = strNeu;
    },
});
```

Complete File on Github.
https://github.com/DIYDave/MySQL-and-Google-Line-Chart

Result:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJQus.jpg)

Comment: Your PHP code is highly vulnerable to SQL injections. Additionally, why is `getData` never called? This won't work from the first steps

Comment: Thank you for your hint. How can I protect against SQL injections? I understood it like this: At the first call no PHP code is executed until in the JS part this place is reached: 'code' google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart(){
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo getData()[0]?>);

Comment: @Nico Haase. I just googled about SQL injection. Alright I will improve that. Many Thanks